# Python: "bad interpreter: No such file or directory" when running django-admin.py

Tags: python, django

I've googled the hell out of this, but all of the solutions I've found seem to solve problems that are not mine.

I created a project in a virtual environment in `/Users/[user]/Documents/projects/[project]` using `virtualenv` and installed Django.

Later, I deleted that project and installed Django on my system outside of the virtual environment. Now, I am trying to run this:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

However, I am receiving this error message:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py: 
/Users/[user]/Documents/projects/[project]/bin/python:
bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I have found that the only way I can make this work again is by setting up the [project] virtual environment as I had it before with Django installed in it.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm not sure what you did to produce this error, but the fix for you is to change `/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py` [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) to `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

---

Actually if you install django in a virtualenv, the `django-admin.py` will have the shebang set to the python interpreter of your virtualenv, but this script will not be created in `/usr/local/bin/`.

Instead this script will be created in `/<virtualenvpath>/bin/` along with `activate` and the virtualenv python interpreter. You should then move this script to `/usr/local/bin/`.

Comment: Ha! I was checking the shebang in the Django install script instead of the `django-admin.py` script. Thanks for waking me up :)

Comment: I mounted a virtualenv directory inside of a Docker container. I was unable to start gunicorn. I had to edit the shebang in the ./bin/gunicorn file to match that of ./bin/python3  mounted inside of the container. I had installed gunicorn into the virtual environment while not inside the container. I presume this resulted in an unexpected shebang in the ./bin/gunicorn. Otherwise I was getting the *bad interpreter: no such file or directory* error.

Comment: I'm in a situation where I cannot modify the shebang lines on said files (packages are installed through a ci/cd pipeline). In my case, I created a symlink to the python interpreter needed. In my situation, I had /usr/bin/python3 (v 3.8.7) and it was trying to use /usr/bin/python3.8.  Simply did `ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.8` to mitigate the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For me, It was that the last program or script that i *invoked didn't correctly end*. In that case *(base)* marks in front of your command when you are using the terminal[mac].

To deactivate the environment,

```
source deactivate
```

OR // if using conda

```
conda deactivate
```

Comment: In my case in MacOS 11.4 BigSur (M1 ARM) im using conda, so I did two "conda deactivate" to deactivate my personal (DjangoEnv) and (base)

So once my command prompt didn't show the (base) env I just go back to my (DjangoEnv)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For django latest version use

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

This works for me.

change my  to your project name.
No need to use django-admin.py use django-admin only.
Activate your environment. Then use the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when you move your project to a different directory, for example, if your former directory was:
/Users/theuser/complete-ml-ds/sample_project/env/bin/python3-config
then it has to be updated to the new directory at the very top of python3-config file

Update the directory information:

## !/Users/theuser/complete-ml-ds/sample_project/env/bin/python3.8

with your new directory

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and reinstalled Django to resolve this issue

`pip uninstall django`

Then `pip install django`.

P.S. don't forget to install the same Django version as what you were using.