# : bad interpreter: No such file or directory in python

Tags: python

I originally coded in python IDE on windows. Now when I pasted my code in a file on Linux server. Now when I run the script, it gives me this error:

> bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Please tell how to resolve this error.

Comment: Could you paste the first few lines of the script, at least?  Basically, would be helpful to see what your #! line is.

Comment: Also, may be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434484/python-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory-when-running-django-admin-p

Comment: probably u don't have python installed or not in the path.

Comment: do you have a shebang line to inform your shell to invoke the Python interpreter for that your script?

Comment: It could be also that there is written '/usr/local/bin/python2.7' and not '/usr/bin/python2.7'

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Probably you have `\r\n` line endings, where `\r` is carriage return and `\n` is newline

That means that the first line might be like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python\r\n
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/python\r\n
```

so the shell is trying to run the command `python\r`

Comment: I'm not aware of any recent versions of sh/bash/dash/ksh that behave this way

Comment: It's actually the kernel itself that handles this, not the shell. And yes, this is a possibility.

Comment: +1 I'm pretty sure this is the explanation.

Comment: `vi` has a "dos-mode". If it's creating a file like that, you've probably got something in your `.virc` that's turning it on by default. [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82726/convert-dos-line-endings-to-linux-line-endings-in-vim)

Comment: same problem, I resolved it using dos2unix file.py to convert newline chars.

Answer (score 12):

You're probably using the `#!python` hashbang convention that's inexplicably popular among Windows users. Linux expects a full path there. Use either `#!/usr/bin/python` or (preferably) `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead.

Comment: would be preferable in some cases to use `#!python` because it takes python from the path - e.g. to be executed in the context of a `venv`.

Comment: A workaround is to open the file in xed editor (linux mint default text editor) Choose Save As and in the Line Ending drop down menu on the bottom, choose Unix/Linux instead of windows. This will clear up the line ending incompatibilities.

Comment: Today I learned about `#!python`